# open emoji keyboard on button click in ios (iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, emoji

I want to open emoji keyboard on a button click into my app. Is this possible to do?

By default it will appear english version keyboard, but on click of a button default keyboard replace with emoji keyboard.

Is it possible to do this without enabling emojis via system preferences?

Comment: Its not possible to do so without creating your own custom emoji keyboard

Comment: Is there any library for custom emoji keyboard?

Comment: Either try this http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/19/enable-emoji-keyboard-iphone/ or https://github.com/ayushgoel/AGEmojiKeyboard

Comment: Please check below links:  http://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/emoji-in-iphone-and-how-to-enable-it/